# How do you increment a variable name in for loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

How do you increment a variable name in loop in C? For example I have a variable K1 and I want to increment the name by one everytime I go through the loop to K2, K3, K4 and so on. I cannot use an array as I have about 1000 variables to cycle through.

UPDATE: I should have clarified that I am programming a microcontroller and the space on board is quite limited. The variable names I wish to loop through are structures, each 8 bytes long. Thus to create an array of the structures I have previously created, I would have to write out an array with 1000 array names? Surely there is a way to increment the names?
I will post up my code in a moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct reg0 {
    int address;
    union {
        struct {
            unsigned int bitfield1 : 1;
            unsigned int bitfield2 : 4;
            unsigned int bitfield3 : 2;
            unsigned int bitfield4 : 1;
        };
        uint8 DATA;
    };
} Reg0;

//Beneath this I have 1000 similar Register structures, each unique


int main()
{
    //Beneath this I have 1000 similar initializations, each unique
    Reg0 R0 = {.address = 0x0,      {{.bitfield1=0x1,.bitfield1=0x6,.bitfield3=0x2,.bitfield4=0x1}}};

for(i=0;i<=1000;i++){
    //Here I'd like to print each address field of each structure to the screen
    printf("Address of Reg%d is: %?", i, Ri);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use an array... 1000 items isn't a lot. You can handle millions easily.

Comment: *I cannot use an array as I have about 1000 variables to cycle through.* I would say you **cannot** use variables as ***you would have 1000 variables to cycle through*** .... In C you can't create variables on the fly at runtime and change their names. That's what arrays are for

Comment: If you have 1000 variables called `K1`...`K999`, do not modify your code any further before learning about arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it through variable names; names are for humans and are no longer present at runtime.

The proper way to model it is using an array. So replace this:

```
int K1, K2, K3, K4, ... K1000;
```

with:

```
int K[1000];
```

Then use a loop index to access into the array:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof K / sizeof *K; ++i)
  K[i]++;
```

If you *really* can't flatten the variables into an array, you can add indirection and have an array of pointers, but it's going to be horrible to initialize:

```
int K1, K2, K3, ... K1000;
int *K[1000] = { &K1, &K2, &K3, ..., &K1000 };
```

Then you can use a loop again:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof K / sizeof *K; ++i)
  (*K[i])++;
```

Note: the `...` above are just notation here in the answer, that's not C syntax. You're supposed to type more stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you cannot.

One the program is compiled into binary, there is no existance of the *variable name* as such. So, you cannot chnage that *at runtime*.

However, using a MACRO you can *somehow* achieve this, but then, that's neither runtime nor a good approach, least being portable and supported accross platforms.

**TL;DR answer** :: Use an array. That's what arrays are meant for.

---

EDIT:

You can use an array of the structure and use the index to access individual elements in the arrary. That should serve your purpose.

Comment: Actually, you can't do this with C macros. The C preprocessor oddly can do math (for tests) but cannot use math to generate names. It also cannot loop, except through recursive includes, which will probably break it.

Comment: @Yann You can with the special builtin counter macro provided by some compilers.

Comment: Then you're out of the bounds of the C standard (for instance, using GNU C extensions, where this is called `__COUNTER__`). Thanks for the hint though.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't. C does not do runtime manipulation of names; in fact, the names themselves may not exist at that point. Secondly, what makes you unable to use arrays? Not only do they not have a problem containing thousands of entries, they're the sane way to handle such things (other structures like linked lists may be usable).